# URL to file in non web accessible directory (Readfile()? Fopen()?...)

Tags: php, file, download

so files are uploaded to a non web accessible directory on my server, but i want to provide a URL or some for of download access to these files. Below is my attempt, but it isn't working.

```
$destination = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/../Uploads/" . $random;
mkdir($destination);
move_uploaded_file($temp, $destination."/".$name);

$final = $server."/".$destination."/".$name;

**$yourfile = readfile('$final');**
```

and i then echo our $yourfile:

```
<?php echo $yourfile; ?>
```

elsewhere.

I either get a failed to open stream, or a huge long string. Is there any solution to just download the file on request via URL?

**EDIT: I want to keep the directory non web accessible.**

Comment: @mario Thanks for your reply mario, so what do you suggest i use instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to URL Link to file outside root directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862307/how-to-url-link-to-file-outside-root-directory)

Answer (score 2):

[`readfile`](http://php.net/readfile) outputs the content directly, it does not return it. Alternatively read the manual page on file_get_contents.

`readfile('$final');` is never going to succeed. Unless the file literally had the "`$final`" name. Double quotes or no quotes.

Your question has been answered a few hundred times already. There's no need for you to post your issue four times in a row.

- [PHP display/download directory files outside the webserver root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382219/php-display-download-directory-files-outside-webserver-root-problem)
- [How to serve documents from outside the web root using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701771/how-to-serve-documents-from-outside-the-web-root-using-php)
- [Display all images from outside web root folder using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761834/display-all-images-from-outside-web-root-folder-using-php)
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20readfile%20from%20outside%20docroot